# Selenium_Webdriver_Python: Send_Keys (Keys + Keys.Enter ) is not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver, sendkeys

I'm trying to send the keys by passing a variable inside it (var name : NextDayFormatted).Because it is a string and to avoid any future error I'm using the below code-

browser.find_element_by_css_selector("...").send_keys(NextDayFormatted + Keys.Enter)

Whenever I'm running this single line of code independently, it works fine. But, when I'm running all , it fails. It is passing the value that I have assigned to my variable (NextDayFormatted) but doesn't hit ENTER due to which the next line of code is failing.

PS: This issue persists in ENTER and RETURN both.

Can you please guide me on this?

```
Full code:

browser.get("url")
username = "abcd"
pwd = "def"
email = browser.find_element_by_name('email')
email.send_keys(username)

password = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys(pwd)

browser.find_element_by_tag_name('button').click()

#Click on filter icon 
browser.find_element_by_xpath('....').click()

#Click Add filter
browser.find_element_by_xpath('....').click()

#Select the fields from the dropdown - Appointment Start Date & After
browser.find_element_by_xpath('....').click()

#The file needs to be extracted on every fridays therefore apply the appointment strt date logic in the search box.

Next_Date = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days = 2)
Next_Date_Formatted = next_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

#Applying the above variable in the search box 
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('....').send_keys(Next_Date_Formatted + Keys.ENTER)`enter code here`

#Click on submit button
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('....').click()
```

Comment: can you share all your code and a page you are working on?

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for your quick response. I'm afraid I won't be able to share the code with you here because of privacy of the data.For your reference, please  find the details below:
The code will help me in future to download the excel file from the desired web page. by applying the filters within a specific timerange .A field  has the search box wherein I have to add my NextDayFormatted = '02/24/2022' (It has the logic of current date + 2 days) and next step after this is to click on "Apply Filter"

Comment: I understand the privacy issue, however currently I'm not sure I will be able to help here, missing basic debugging details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The full code is provided in the description. Thanks

Comment: I'm still waiting for this.